# How to be sure that non-blocking socket send from client (on linux) has actually sent data to server?

Tags: linux, sockets, nonblocking

How to be sure that non-blocking socket send from client (on linux) has actually sent data to server?

I have client socket send() done in non-blocking fashion over wifi network wherein send() indicates that send has been done without any error.
While looking at wireshark logs I find that there are lots of re-transmissions happening over the wifi network for this send.
I also realize that socket cannot force the data in the buffer as explained in the link (http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.11.shtml)
So in such a condition is it possible for client socket to know that actual send has not yet happened? If so how?
Detecting such a condition would help me, for e.g., to close the socket and then try sending it again after sometime.

-vj.

Comment: The trouble with your question is how to define whether or not the data has been sent. Do you consider is successfully send when the data has been submitted to the kernel? ...encapsulated in TCP segments to be sent out? ...submitted to the network interface (and what if it's a virtual interface like a tunnel?)? ...placed on the wire? ...pulled off the wire at the other end? ...acknowledged by the remote TCP stack? ...confirmed acknowledged by the local TCP stack? ...passed to the remote socket? ...delivered to userspace on the remote end?

Comment: This is not possible, if you need to know that your application data have reached the other side, you will need to send application level ACKs for you data.

Comment: The only reliable way of knowing is receiving the server's answer. If you get that, you can be sure the server got your request.

Comment: @Celada - You have really pointed out the diffeent stages of send. It would help me to know that data has been actually sent out and has been acknowledged by remote TCP stack. Is it not possible for client socket to know that re-transmissions are being tried out? Will select() help in send for non-blocking socket? Does use of blocking socket would make a difference for such a behavior?

Comment: @nos - by application level ACKs for data, does it mean that server side sends ack for client socket send() or something else itself?

Comment: @Damon - what you say is absolutely correct. in my case since re-transmissions are happening and it is taking time while client socket thinks that send() is done and trying to do read() for response form server that it does not get. It would help client socket to know about this wrong behavior of re-transmissions (could be wifi issue) so that it can close it much more before.

Comment: @v.j Yes, it means your server must send() back a message telling your client that it received a message. (also, non-blocking sockets makes no difference - though it's easier to implement timeouts with non-blocking sockets.)